# Trouble with CSS transition, absolute positioning, and React Transition Group

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-transition-group

I'm working on some basic FreeCodeCamp challenges, and I'm trying to use React Transition Group to achieve some pretty simple animations. Here's the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/murphyg/pen/qBWpLda).

What I've run in to is that I can't find out how to have the "quote card" horizontally and vertically centered, and also have my animations (that I'm using React Transition Group to trigger) perform a translation on it. I have the element that I'm trying to move (`#quote-box`) centered with the following css:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Here're the "move" CSS classes that I'm using with the Transition Group:

```
.move-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transform: translate(-200px, 0);
}

.move-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in 200ms;
}

.move-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.move-exit-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transform: translate(200px, 0);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in 200ms;
}
```

I assume that I should be setting the `transition` properties to be `left` instead of `all`, but I'm a little lost in what is preventing the movement from happening. Should I also have a `move-exited` and `move-entered` class with the appropriate positioning? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pretty major hint as to what might be going wrong here, and that is the fact that in your CodePen, the cards successfully animate their `opacity` but not their `transform`. That tells you that *something* is working as expected, just not *all* of the transition.

So, our first step would be to investigate the transition as it happens. Indeed, if we slow down the CSS transition duration to 20 seconds and set the `<ReactTransitionGroup.CSSTransition>` timeout also to 20 seconds, and inspect the element `div#quote-box` with devtools as the transition is happening, we see something fishy:

[image]

Your CSS transform property for `#quote-box` is overriding the transition group transform property for `.move-enter-active` (as expected - see [CSS selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)) (you can tell because the `transform` property in `.move-enter-active` is crossed out). In other words, your CSS transition group transform is never applied, but the `opacity` transition is unaffected because `#quote-box` does not set that property.

There are a few potential solutions here. One of the most simple involves two steps:

1. Change `#quote-box` from an ID to a class (`.quote-box`) - (you should absolutely do this anyway, and also for any IDs on the page, because you should only ever have a single instance of the same named ID on the page, and with CSS transition group you will have at least two at some points.) This will also ensure that your CSS transition group `.move-*` selectors will have the proper priority.

```
// CSS
.quote-box {
  // etc
}

// JSX
<div className="quote-box" >
  {/* etc */}
</div>
```

2. Adjust your CSS to use the `calc()` function to calculate the position of the quote box. This is because normally you would not be able to center the quote box with `transform(-50%, -50%)` *and* offset its position for the transition with `transform(-200px, 0)` at the same time. To do so, we must use `calc()` to combine *both* the centering transform *and* the transition offset at the same time, i.e. `transform: translate(calc(-50% - 200px), -50%);`:

```
.move-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% - 200px), -50%);
}

.move-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in 200ms;
}

.move-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.move-exit-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 200px), -50%);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in 200ms;
}
```

https://codepen.io/_jered/pen/KKPomVK

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for such a clear and well-explained answer! This all makes a lot of sense, thanks for pointing out the feature in the debugging tool to see when a property has been overridden. One point that I'm not fully understanding, though, is never using IDs for a single-instance. I believe that this is important, but I don't fully get the reasoning, are there any good resources you know of that could explain this more fully? Thanks again!

Comment: @GoodTimeHaver For any given `id` string, there must be only a single unique element on the page that is assigned that `id`. As opposed to `class` which is fine to share across multiple elements. The reasons for this are numerous, perhaps the most compelling being that it is part of the HTML specification itself: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes:html-elements-5